# how to use sun.audio with java 9

Tags: java-9, sun

i am working on adapting my desktop app to run with jre9
i get

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/audio/AudioStream`

i had some other problems with sun API that i resolved by adding the jvm args
`--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED`
but in those cases the error was of type `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` so exporting the model solved the problem.

any idea how can keep using the `sun.audio`? of course i can try to switch to a different library like `javax.sound` but i have some legacy code that i rather not touch.

i tried some options like `--add-open` and `--illegal-access` but assuming the `sun.audio` api was removed form the sdk those options won't make any difference

Comment: The sun.audio package was a JDK internal API, it was removed in JDK 9 (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050465). JavaSound has been in Java SE since 1.3.

Comment: Thanks Alan! Can i use it by importing a specific jar that contains that package?

Comment: It was a JDK internal API, I'm not aware of any way to use it outside of JDK 8 and older.

Answer (score 2):

As Alan Bateman commented, sun.audio packages [were removed from jdk9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050465).

I ended up replacing the usage of the sun.audio package in my code.